# Build error in System.Double.cs, floating point constant range

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, double

I have a project in Visual Studio 2008 using the .NET 2.0 framework. When I build the project I get two build errors showing as red crosses, but the project still builds successfully. Even more strangely, the errors are in System.Double.cs. The error is "Floating-point constant is outside the range of type 'double'" and they point to the lines of code where the MinValue and MaxValue constants are initialised.

Any ideas? It's not a show-stopper since the project still builds, but odd nonetheless.

Thanks, Jon

Comment: Which Double.cs file?  I checked the metadata file and the reference source file, and they don't give any errors.

Comment: It's whichever Double.cs is opened if I 'go to definition' - looks reverse engineered to me - but your answer was spot on!

Comment: What's the value of the constant?  Mine is `1.79769e+308`, and doesn't give an error.

Comment: MinValue = -1.79769313486232E+308; MaxValue = 1.79769313486232E+308; No idea why they error, but it's not a problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have SP1 installed, the IDE will report compilation errors for all open files, even files that are not in your project.

Close the Double.cs file, and the errors will disappear.

Comment: Perfect! Somehow Double.cs had been opened (probably by browse->go to definition), and for whatever reason that was showing compile errors. Closing the file made the compile errors disapper. Thanks.